# Convertir hora en formato HH:MM a int

Tags: c#, asp

Estoy en una encrucijada resulta que estoy haciendo una aplicación .Net que me recibe un valor ejemplo 00:34 y ese valor lo quiero convertir a int para pasarlo a la base de datos ejemplo mi hora que recibo es:

00:14 y quiero convertirlo a un entero en relación que las 00:00 es el entero 1 (obviando el resto) las 01:13 es el entero 2 y así sucesivamente siempre obviando los minutos solo tomando en cuenta las horas acá mi código

```
 movCentrales.Add(new tb_Movimientos_centrales
{

    Fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(dtfechaRio.Rows[0].ToString().Substring(6, 4) + "-" + dtfechaRio.Rows[0].ToString().Substring(3, 2) + "-" + dtfechaRio.Rows[0].ToString().Substring(0, 2)),
    Hora_movimiento = Convert.ToString(drhoraMov["Hora Movi#"]),                                    
    Horario = Convert.ToInt32(drHorario["Hora Movi#"]) +1,
    Central_equipo = Convert.ToString(drCentralEquipo["Central/Equipo"]),
    Consigna = Convert.ToString(drConsigna["Consigna"]),
    Central_Configura = Convert.ToString(drCentralConfigura["F1"]),


});
dbContRio.SaveChanges();
```

La hora que quiero convertir es la variable Horario estaba pensando hacer un convert.toint32 y sumarle uno alguna idea de como hacerlo:
mas info:

```
Hora:
00:14 = 1 --
00:59 = 1 --
01:25 = 2 --
01:00 = 2 --
02:13 = 3 --
```

y asi sucesivamente.

Comment: ¿`Fecha.Hour + 1;`?

Comment: Que te devuelve drhoraMov["Hora Movi#"]??

Comment: No estaria entendiendo donde esta tu problema

Comment: [Hora Mov#] devuelve la columna con las horas del excel que cargo

Comment: Mi problema es que desde el excel viene en este formato

12/03/2018 12:00 AM quiero tomar ese 12:00AM y convertirlo a un int 
en este caso seria No tomar la fecha tomar la hora 12:00AM y ese valor guardarlo en una variable tipo int que tendria el valor 1 para la hora 12:00AM para la hora 01:00AM seria el valor 2 y asi sucesivamente

Comment: Cual es el valor que quieres convertir? `Fecha`? `drHorario["Hora Movi#"]`? No se entiende bien la pregunta

Comment: el valor a Rescatar es la hora, sin los minutos solo la hora esa hora convertirla a entero ejemplo las 00:00 es la hora 0 y a ese cero sumarle 1 y ese 1 guardar en la variable para enviarlo a la BD

Comment: Eso ya te lo respondió @NaCl: `var numero = Convert.ToDateTime("01:59").Hour + 1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que convertir le valor de `drHorario["Hora Movi#"]` a una fecha para poder tener la hora esta la puedes hacer mediante  la selección de una parte del string  o haciendo un `Convert.ToDateTime()` al valor  `drHorario["Hora Movi#"]` y usar la propiedad `Hour`.

```
//Ejemplo 1
Horario = Convert.ToInt32(drHorario["Hora Movi#"].ToString().Substring(0, 2)) +1

//Ejemplo 2
Horario = Convert.ToDateTime(drHorario["Hora Movi#"].ToString()).Hour + 1
```

En ambos ejemplos debes validar que es un formato correcto de horas y minutos  para un mejor control de excepciones.

Comment: El motivo de añadir `"01/01/2000 "` cual es? :)

Comment: @Pikoh Es solo tener un formato de fecha valido que pueda ser convertido ya que  no se puede hacer  con  HH:mm.

Comment: Estás seguro de que no se puede hacer? prueba `var numero = Convert.ToDateTime("01:59").Hour + 1;`

Comment: @Pikoh tienes razón si se puede hacer con solo el formato `HH:mm` Actualizo mi respuesta :).

Comment: `toDateTime` es suficientemente inteligente para darse cuenta de que es una hora, y le añade la fecha actual. Tambien se puede usar `DateTime.Parse` y tambien lo entenderá. Y si no, se puede usar `DateTime.ParseExact("03:22", "HH:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` al que puedes pasarle el formato exacto de los datos que le pasas.

Answer (score 0):

No tienes que convertir nada, las horas ya son conceptualmente un valor entero. Los ordenadores almacenan las fechas (en la mayoría de casos) como [la cantidad de segundos transcurridos desde la medianoche UTC del 1 de enero de 1970](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_Unix).

Para eso C# ofrece la estructura [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx), si lo quieres guardar en base de datos puedes [pasar un `DateTime` a entero](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx#Integers) con la propiedad [`Ticks`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.datetime.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
long ahora = DateTime.Now.Ticks; // Guarda 'ahora' en base de datos.
```

Para recuperar el dato tan sólo haz el proceso inverso:

```
long dato = 0; // Lee 'dato' de la base de datos.
var antes = new DateTime(dato).
```

Comment: Esta respuesta y la orientación de uso me parece mucho más *limpia*